# \0 doesn't work in re.sub(). way around?

Tags: python, regex

In Python,

```
re.sub('(ab)c', r'\1d', 'xxxabcxxx')
```

gives me back `'xxxabdxxx'`.

You would expect `re.sub('(ab)c', r'\0d', 'xxxabcxxx')` to return  `'xxxabcdxxx'`. That is, you'd expect it to work in a similar way to `m.group(0)`.

However, this isn't supported. http://bugs.python.org/issue17426#msg184210

What is a simple way to achieve what `re.sub('(ab)c', r'\0d', 'xxxabcxxx')` should achieve, without the use of `re.sub()`?

Comment: it get's interpreted as a [null byte](https://bugs.python.org/issue17426#msg184212)

Answer (score 10):

Use `\g<0>`.  You can also use `\g<1>`, etc. for other groups, but `0` is the entire match.

This is explained in the documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: yeh. I maybe could have made this a little more explicit. I am looking for a way way that doesn't use re.sub() at all (it is for an assignment).

Comment: @user2862886 what is the specification for the assignment?